# Refresh only a div from the same page, no external source

Tags: jquery, refresh

Im trying to refresh a div tag with jquery but it is not working..
i need to refresh a div so the php code gets executed and a text updated..

first i load jquery then the file that contains function i need to execute, and then refresh script, all on header:

```
  <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

  <?php
     require "codes.php";
  ?>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      setInterval(function(){
         $('#ip').load('#ip');
      }, 1000);
  </script>
```

finally the div i want refreshed:

```
<div id="ip" class="navbar-header">
     <p style="text-align: center; color:white;">
         Your IP address is 
         <span style="color:red;">
            <?php
                echo getip();
            ?>
         </span>
     </p>
```

Comment: You asked a very nice question. Developers who prefer serverside language like PHP for large project with less use of clientside language like javascript are forced to change their programming tools and patterns for this loading or reloading issues only. Reloading a div clientside on the same page without calling any external file would help PHP programmers to stick with serverside language more genuinely although PHP always has the way to perform the same tasks that javascript, javascript libraries & javascript frameworks can do but in little different ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your php `echo` will run once when page is opened. As the name of PHP which is abbr of (Hypertext Preprocessor ... *bla bla bla*) *forgot* ... so your php code will finally turn into just static html content on your page. Your js `setInterval()` and jQuery `.load()` is actually running but the `$('#ip')` content is still the same.

To be able to get data dynamicaly, you (must) need an external php file which will process the request of `echo getip();` again and again.

### So like this:

**loadip.php**

```
echo getip();
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(loadip,1000);
});

function loadip() {
    $("#ip").load("loadip.php");
}
```

Or ...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#ip").load("loadip.php");
    },1000);
});
```

Hope this help. Good luck!